# Generating password inside a directory with "pass" fails with "No public key"

Tags: debian, password-store

It fails when I try to generate/insert a password inside a given directory, 'private' in this example:

```
$ pass generate private/test
: skipped: No public key
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: No public key
Password encryption aborted.
```

However generating a password without any directory works just fine:

```
$ pass generate test
[master a62efe8] Add generated password for test.
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test.gpg
The generated password for test is:
Q"q~~s03oEvv4'5j6P!I#=!w:
```

Tried exporting and importing key, trusting it ultimately, but nothing works.
It might be important to notice, that on my other machine with exactly same setup and same key I can generate a password in any directory without any problem.